# Restart apache remotely?

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm connected to a remote mac using ssh + terminal. I need to restart apache from terminal. How can I do that?

I am looking here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html and tried:

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

but this command seems to not be found. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use the init scripts.  Try something like:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: It's `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start` because /etc/init.d is not in OSX

Answer (score 0):

How about `apache2ctl`?